# Cant Enable audio on through xfreerdp. Remmina works

Tags: rdp, remmina, xfreerdp

Guys please help me enabling audio via xfreeRdp.
It works for me better then remmina. Only issue I have is audio

I can hear remote (Windows 7) PC  audio (rg from youtube) on my Linux box only when Im connecting via remmina.
Can manage same via xfreeRdp command line.
**Is there any way to see what params Remmina passes to xfreerdp ?**

what I've tried:

```
/audio-mode:1
/sound:sys:alsa 
/sound 
--plugin drdynvc --data audin -- server
--plugin rdpsnd --data pulse -- server
/sound /microphone:sys:alsa
```

Nothing of above was working...

PS my linux laptop is My laptop is Lenovo x220

xfreerdp verison: 1.1.0-beta1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Ive resolved that by installing freerdp2

```
sudo apt-get install freerdp2-x11
```

then it was enough to use /sound switch